# Angular 4 project that consists of multiple sub projects

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, clean-architecture

I am developing cross-platform mobile app with Angular 4, Ionic 3 and Cordova. I want to have my project divided into sub-projects in a way that I would have multiple sub projects that each of them have their own dependencies independent of other project. My goal is to use clean architecture in this project.

For example, I would like to have `cache`, `remote` and `data` sub projects. Sub projects `cache` doesn't need dependency to http module so I don't want to be able to use it in that module and similarly I don't want to use classes from `cache` and `remote` sub projects anywhere else but `data` sub project so my coworkers can't screw it up in future.

In the end I want to achive project similar to [this](https://github.com/bufferapp/clean-architecture-components-boilerplate) but this is native Android project.

Comment: Create an angular `module` for each "project"/"sub project". You can separate the modules as you see fit. Options would be including them in the sources folder of the root project, keeping them in their own sources folder and referencing them in your main project using a relative path, or keep them as isolated projects and create a private npm store and import the modules that way.

Comment: @Igor Since I'm fairly new to Angular and JS development this solution seems complicated but I'll try it if I have time. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Then just create modules in 1 project, the angular tour of heroes tutorial walks you through it. It allows you to create modular code packages.

Comment: u can find an example description on how to organize ur project structure in clean architecture here: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Scream/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by separating your project into several modules, and managing your dependencies in these different modules to meet your needs.

For example, you can create 3 modules :

- CacheModule (app/cache/cache.module.ts + components) providing cache services and declare/export components
- RemoteModule (app/remote/remote.module.ts + components) providing remote/http services...
- DataModule (app/data/data.module.ts + components) providing data services...

And to split a little more your app, avoiding your coworkers to touch code that they don't need to, you can create git submodules into your project : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules